# extracting just first order terms of equation

Tags: python, sympy

I need to extract just the terms of the equation which just have one term of `tau`. 
I have been using the `SymPy` module but I am new to it.

I have an equation similar to this (which arises from some matrix manipulations).

```
m=cos(alpha)*sin(theta)+
  cos(alpha)*sin(theta)*sin(tau)+
  sin(theta)*sin(tau)*cos(tau)+
  sin(tau)**2
```

Then using `O(tau**2)` and doing something like

```
m2=m+O(tau**2)
m1=m2.removeO()+O(tau)
m1=m-m1.removeO()
```

To leave me with m1 being just the tau terms.
This almost works however it won't pick up the `sin(theta)*sin(tau)*cos(tau)` term. To be clear I need this to be picked up in the `tau**2` terms.

If I use the Euler identities this will give a term of the form `e**2tau` where I am only interested in the `e**tau` terms. However I can't see a way to do this all in terms of exponentials and just strip out the `e**(tau)` terms.

It is in fact the exponential terms that I am interested in just the tau and not the 2tau terms (these terms have a different physical meaning). However I am struggling to find a way to go about it.

I presume there is an obvious answer that I am just missing.

Comment: it's a bit complicated - let me ask for clearence. 
you have `M = x*y+x*y*z+y*z*sqrt(1-z**2)+z**2` and you roughly want sth. like `f(z) = M/f(x, y)`?